# Saving previous field value with BPC web powerforms or nintex workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2013, nintex-workflow

Using nintex workflow; I have a switch with various statuses.
  What I am trying to accomplish: capture the previous status value and store as a          hidden column.

This way, if I have reached Status 4, then the item is switched back to Status 3, the workflow will respond differently than if it were hitting Status 3 for the first time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would try using a state machine for your last stage. That way you can have the workflow change to an altered version of Stage 3.